# Auth Dialog Customization

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

How can we change the "Goto App" button text like in "The Guardian" app?
Is this a standart text for "read" action?

[image: The Guardian Facebook App Auth Dialog]

Comment: +1, sure would like to know how we can change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit of research while working with my client and found that this can only be done when you are using custom actions, the apps you are talking about like yahoo or any other had previously approved **read** actions, now Facebook is not accepting custom **read** actions instead you have to use built-in action other wise your action will not be approved.

Answer (score 0):

i think the answer be here :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#define

Comment: In the tutorials and examples I can't see the example of changing th "Goto app" button text like in http://i.stack.imgur.com/FQQy5.png

Comment: i told you i think ,
Cause there is the place you define whats your app about